# python counting funktion for text output in a loop

Tags: python, counter

I have a working code which tells me, when a laser and a photoresistor will be interrupted.

It would be great, when I can write the information of time into a file and also a counting (i=i+1). So this will be done normally every 2 seconds. A writing after e.g. 500 breaks would be great, because it is running at a rasyperry pi. Less writing would be great.

My output file should be something like this with unix time stamp. So I do not know where do I have to put my counter i = i + 1 at which position and the second question is about the caching issue.

```
12341234.12341234 1
123478.234789 2
12342134.12341234 3
78989123.12341234 4
```

Code

```
import os, time
from time import strftime,localtime
 
RECEIVER_PIN = 23
 
def callback_func(channel):
    if GPIO.input(channel):
        print("Sensor1: Lichtschranke wurde unterbrochen")
        date_local = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime())
        ticks = time.time()
        print(date_local)
        print(ticks)
        with open("/home/pi/Documents/sensors/sensor01_tageswert.txt","a+") as sensor01:
        #    sensor01.write(date_local)
            sensor01.write(str(ticks))
            sensor01.write("\n")
        # alternativ kann ein Script / Shell Befehl gestartet werden
        # os.system("ls")
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    
    GPIO.setup(RECEIVER_PIN, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(RECEIVER_PIN, GPIO.RISING, callback=callback_func, bouncetime=200)
        
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.25)
    except:
        # Event wieder entfernen mittels:
        GPIO.remove_event_detect(RECEIVER_PIN)
```

Comment: not what you asked, but Python built-in `logging` plus debian/raspbian `logrotate` can do all of this a lot better with less effort, while also being thread-safe

Comment: Do you have a example? I want to have at least a text file, which I can use with the following to get a graph. import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time